# Why is this scheme $Y$ an affine bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, vector-bundles

Suppose you have $F$ a subbundle of a vector bundle $E\to X$ over a scheme $X$. Recall that there is a scheme $\varphi\colon Y\to X$ with the points of $Y$ over the point $x\colon\mathrm{spec}(A)\to X$ are the morphisms $x^*(E)\to x^*(F)$ which restrict to the identity on $x^*(F)$.

I have two hiccups in my reading: is there an explanation of why $Y$ is affine, with $\varphi^*(F)$ a direct summand of $\varphi^*(E)$?

Comment: I mean, $Y$ needn't be affine in general. Take the trivial bundle over a non-affine scheme. The morphism $\varphi$ is affine though--that's just because definitionally, locally on the base it looks like $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\times\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Am I misunderstanding your question?